# Is it possible to create a RandomForestClassifier through scikit.learn that predicts hierarchical classes/labels?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, multi-index

I am wondering if it is possible to create a RandomForestClassifier that can predict a hierarchy of classes. In other words, I would like to create a RFC where the first level of labels are mutually exclusive whereas the second levels do not necessarily have to be. A simple example of such a scenario would be predicting types of fruits as well as their colors. You could have different fruits that have the same descriptive colors, but a fruit would never be both an apple and a tomato.

Of course, I am not actually working with fruits and colors, but the issue is principally the same and I thought this would make my question easier to grasp.

I've done extensive searches so far, including reading through a lot of the scikit documentation. What I am looking for does not seem to be described in their Multiclass page (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html)

I also tried combining the two levels into one and then creating an RFC based on those labels. What I mean by that is that rather than having a 2D array where the first represents the fruit (Tomato) and the second color (Red), I combined the strings into a 1D array (TomatoRed). Of course, this worked. However, I am highly interested in the feature importance, and since this method treats all the different "permutations" of fruit+color as inherently different (for instance TomatoRed and TomatoYellow become two completely unrelated classes), I believe it may not give an accurate representation of the feature importance. Furthermore, it may over-/underestimate the accuracy of the predictions.

I also tried just making a 2D array and seeing what happens. In doing so, when I pass RFC.predict, I get a ValueError telling me it could not convert string to float followed by the name of one of the labels. I know for a fact that the data array containing feature data are only floats.

So, what I would like to know is if this is possible through sklearn? If necessary, I will add a snippet of code to represent my problem, but I do not think it would help. Please let me know if you find it necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your example is a bit confusing, I understand "a fruit would never be both an apple and a tomato" part, but can a fruit (in your scenario) be both red and green? so a single sample can have 1 or 2 color or 3 or zero color?

Comment: No, the same sample cannot be both red and green. However, two different samples of tomatoes could have two different colors, one red and one green. A single sample needs to have one, and only one, color. So basically, what I am trying to do is classify sample X by assigning it a fruit and a color.

Comment: Then I believe this falls under `Multioutput-multiclass classification` of your link

Comment: I agree with you in that it is the one that is closest to what I am looking for. However, it's not a perfect fit. I will look into other options. Thanks for your effort.